# Подключение dll файла через интернет

Tags: c#

Всем привет! Разрабатываю одну программу (с платной подпиской), хочу сделать так, чтобы программа брала все библиотеки с моего сервера (при отсутствии подписки - библиотеки не должны быть доступны). У меня два вопроса:

1. Как динамически подключить dll, которая находится на сервере, при
   запуске программы?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы данные dll были
   доступны только из моей программы? Чтобы просто так скачать их было
   нельзя.

Comment: 1. Причем тут asp.net и asp.net-core? 2. Что из себя представляет ваша программа? Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/675842/edit), воспользуйтесь ей и дополните ваш вопрос необходимой информацией, пока вопросов к вам больше чем ответов для вас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать, называется *[RPC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80)*. Другими словами вы отправляете на сервер название функции и её параметры, а в ответ получаете результат выполнения функции.

Самый удобный механизм RPC называется *[SOAP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)*. Удобен он тем, что сервер предоставляет описание функций в виде *[WSDL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL)* файла, на основе которого может быть сгенерирован код на любом языке. К примеру, если сервер поддерживает, то можно вызвать функцию `sumOfTwoNumber(5,6)` и она вернёт `11`. При этом сгенерированный код сам преобразует функцию и параметры в формат понятный серверу, передаст на сервер и получит от сервера ответ.

Насколько я помню, в *C#* можно подключать веб-сервисы (человеческое название *SOAP*) как простые пакеты.
Нужно иметь ввиду, что данные между клиентом и сервером передаются в формате *XML*, из-за чего трафик может быть большим и медленным. А без интернета функции и вовсе работать не смогут.

Comment: Веб-сервисы (SOAP) давно считаются устаревшими. Лучше использовать WCF или модный ныне WebAPI.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну если по честному, то WCF за кадром как раз таки использует SOAP-сообщения, собственно ради упрощения работы с SOAP он и создавался..

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть в данную сторону)

Answer (score 0):

А программа-то что из себя представляет? ASP.Net приложение?
А что за Dll? .Net сборка или Win32 dll?
В первом случае взломать защиту довольно легко. Во втором см. методы защиты нативных Win32 приложений.
Единственный годный вариант защиты для чисто .Net онлайн-приложения - вынесение части функций в какие-нибудь сервисы на Вашем сервере, к которым будут обращаться подписчики со своими аутентификационными токенами.